# How to select two table parent and child hierarchy using joins in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I am try to select parent child hierarchy from two different tables, but am not getting correct output..if any one know tell me..

```
Table1

Id      title     
1         a1
2         b   
3         c1
4         d1 

Table2

Id      title    pid
1         a     null
2         b         1
3         c         2
4         d         1
```

Check if the table1 id equal to table2 pid then get table1 title.

Output Like

```
Id title
1     a1
2      a1<b    
3      a1<b<c1 
4       a1<d1

SELECT T2.PId AS MId, CASE WHEN T2.Id IS NOT NULL THEN T2.Title + '>' + T1. title ELSE T1. title END AS title, T2.Id AS PId 
FROM(SELECT T0.Id AS Id, CASE WHEN T1.Id IS NOT NULL THEN T1.Title + '>' + T0. title ELSE T0.title END AS title, T1.PId AS PId 
FROM (SELECT T1.PgeId AS MnuId, T1.Title  AS title, adnMNU.PId AS PId 
FROM TABLE1 T1 join TABLE2 ON T1.Id = TABLE2.Id ) T0
  Left JOIN adnPGE T2 ON T0.PId=T1.Id )T1
  Left JOIN adnPGE T3 ON T1.PId=T2.Id
```

Comment: Is the 'Output Like' the output you want or the output you get?

Comment: how come your output has `a1` for `1`, its not `table1 id equal to table2 pid`

Comment: if paraent id is null take table one title..

Comment: This exception and the title for 3 shows we are not dealing with a normal parent-child-thing but with a custom function to compute the title.
You need somebody to get the intend and debug that complicated select.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a recursive common table expression (CTE). One note, it doesn't look like you're using the titles from Table2. Just an observation; it doesn't hurt my feelings any. As such, I created a view of the data that uses the Ids from Table2 and the titles from Table1.

```
with Table1 as (
    select * from (values
        (1, 'a1'),
        (2, 'b '),  
        (3, 'c1'),
        (4, 'd1')
    ) as x(Id, title)
), Table2 as (
    select * from (values

        (1, 'a', null),
        (2, 'b', 1   ),
        (3, 'c', 2   ),
        (4, 'd', 1   )
    ) as x(Id, title, pid)
), combined as (
    select b.Id, a.title, b.pid
    from Table1 as a
    join Table2 as b
        on a.Id = b.Id
), r_cte as (

    select *, cast(title as varchar(max)) as [path]
    from combined
    where pid is null

    union all

    select child.*, cast(concat(parent.[path], '>', child.title) as varchar(max))
    from r_cte as parent
    join combined as child
        on child.pid = parent.Id
)
select * 
from r_cte
order by id;
```